# Complex numbers singularites

Tags: complex-numbers

I was recently watching a video about residue theorem, and I got confused on one part which he didn't explain in details

how does this 
$$z^4+1=0$$

lead to that $$z=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}n)}$$

where $n=0,1,2,3$

Comment: Does it have anything to do with eulners identity? since $z^4=-1$ so we can write it as $e^{i\pi}=-1$?

Comment: $z^4=-1$ says that $z^8=1$, so $z$ is an $8$-th root of unity, i.e., a power of $e^{2\pi i/8}$. Then use $\ker(\exp))=2\pi i \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $|z|=1$, let $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ then $z^4=\cos4\theta+i\sin4\theta=-1$ which shows $\cos4\theta=-1$ or $4\theta=2k\pi+\pi$ and then 
$$\theta=\dfrac{k\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$
so 
$$z=e^{i\left(\frac{k\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$$
where $k=0,1,2,3$.